# What is the most direct way to get an Active Directory object for a given MAPI/Exchange user?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, exchange-server, mapi

I'm trying to query Active Directory attributes of a MAPI recipient from inside an Outlook COM-addin. This is the first time I'm dealing with AD queries and the only way I figured out so far does not seem entirely ideal, so it would be great if somebody with a little more experience would chime in before I go ahead and implement that approach.

So, here's what I came up with:

1. Read the value of the recipient's `PR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W` MAPI property.
2. Use `IDirectorySearch` to locate an LDAP-entry whose `legacyExchangeDN` attribute matches that value.

That does seem straight-forward enough and the proof-of-concept is working, but:

- I already have a unique ID - why should I have to do an actual **search**? Shouldn't there be some way of accessing the AD user object directly, e.g. by somehow using the information I have about the recipient to construct an LDAP-path that I can simply pass to `ADsGetObject()`?
- The term "legacy" in the attribute name implies that this might not be a good long-term strategy.
- There's actually a step missing from the above list: Before I can use `IDirectorySearch` I need to determine the root container to search. Right now I'm querying "`LDAP://rootDSE`" and then ask for the "`defaultNamingContext`" attribute to formulate a new query with. Is this universally safe? For example, will this also work when my addin's Outlook 2010 host is connected to multiple different Exchange servers and the recipient I need to query is not from the default server?

FWIW, I'm using the excellent [Redemption](http://dimastr.com/redemption) library to access the Extended MAPI layer, so I'm not actually working with `IMailUser` but rather with `IAddressEntry`. So, if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do built into that library feel free to suggest that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of questions inside there, but here goes.

Overall your concept and flow is right.  The thing you have to remember is that Active Directory and Exchange are two different systems. They are tightly integrated, but you still need to search AD to find their account. It doesn't help that MAPI predates Active Directory and hasn't aged well in this managed framework world, so unless there would be something built into Redemption to get the AD user for you, you're on your own.

Ahh, legacyExchangeDN.  Sounds like there's something better on the way, right?  There isn't.  That property has been the main link between the AD account and the Exchange mailbox since Windows 2000 when Active Directory was first released. That's the best way of finding the mailbox's user in Active Directory.  It is safe to use.

Your last bullet item is complicated enough to be it's own question.  For 95% of all Exchange and Active Directory installations, the way you are doing it is fine assuming that your add-in is used on-site or over a VPN.  But the other 5% are very complicated.  You can do some crazy setups with Exchange ranging from different domains to different forests as well as hosted Exchange environments.  Honestly, if you need to be able to query AD from any configuration, I would ask that as it's own question.

In the end, you'll probably be ok for most corporate LAN situations. Hosted Exchange will cause problems because you typically can't get to the backing Active Directory.